# Is it common to use double quotation marks to splice strings in mybatis?

Tags: mysql, mybatis

I think this is a feature of mysql, although I did not search for relevant descriptions in the mysql documentation.

I got the same result in [DBFiddler mysql5.5](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=50952e2d084c96abfc7edb15904bb13e), [DBFiddler mysql8.0](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=50952e2d084c96abfc7edb15904bb13e), which means this is not the client's processing.

This way mybatis can work normally, but I am not sure if it depends on a specific version?
For better compatibility/performance, do I need to replace it with `concat('%',#{name},'%')`?

```xml
<mapper namespace="com.test">
    <select id="test">
        select port_name from d_port
        where port_name like "%"#{name}"%"
    </select>
</mapper>
```

[image]

Comment: No, it is not common. I cannot think of any good reason to use double quotes.

Comment: The double quotes seem to be a syntax shorthand that MySQL understands. If that's the case, it would be OK to use them in the mapper.

Comment: Also, I would recommend you concatenate the parameter in a different as in `like concat('%', ${name}, '%')`. The way you are doing it now is highly vulnerable to SQL Injection.